# VBA Add-In File Reference Path Changing

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have a workbook that is on OneDrive and is shared between multiple people.
The workbook has a reference in VBA to a XLAM file that has several macros used by the workbook.

The XLAM file is on a network drive that everyone has access to.

The file path to the XLAM file keeps changing on its own to a local path in App Data (see picture). This causes it to fail when other people open the workbook because they don't have the file in that local path on their computer.

Is there a way to force excel to keep the original file path?

[image]

I also tried this with a reference to a macro-enabled workbook instead of an XLAM but the same issue occurred.

When I have the macros in the workbook instead of an external file, OneDrive fails to sync the file between the different users about once a week and we keep having to restore previous versions and redo work.
When I remove the macros from the file, our syncing issues go away.